# How can I dynamically format cell borders as user types?

Tags: vba, excel

I've put about 3 full days into writing code and I am not a programmer at all.

I am trying dynamically format cells borders if I type specific characters into the cell, but not for formulas or other inputs.

I have code that sort of works. Runs if I remove the worksheet change event and sub argument, use ActiveCell instead of Target and step through with F8 or run with F5. Sometimes will not format cells properly, but no errors.

Does not work if I use the worksheet event, will not work automatically as I type. It is in a standard module:

```
'super messy - mid draft + I have no idea what I'm doing

Option Explicit
Sub superset_exercise(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell, cellAbove, cellBelow, rangestart As Range
Dim Char, CharAbove, CharBelow As String
Dim strcell, strlengthA, strlengthB As Integer

'set cell reference to the one currently being typed in
Set cell = Target

'checks to see if it's an exercise list. Want only exercise lists formatted
If IsEmpty(Target) = True Then Exit Sub
strcell = InStr(1, cell, ")")
If strcell = 0 Or strcell = 1 Or strcell > 3 Then Exit Sub 'exit without formatting
Selection.Font.Bold = True

'compares active cell to cell above and below, match first letter
Set cellAbove = Target.Offset(-1, 0)    'ActiveCell instead of target?
Set cellBelow = Target.Offset(1, 0)

'Checks to see if cells above or below are empty
If cellAbove = "LIFT" Then If IsEmpty(cellBelow) = True Then GoTo TopEdge Else: GoTo CheckLetter


If IsEmpty(cellAbove) = True And cellAbove.Offset(0, 1) = "LIFT" Then
    If IsEmpty(cellBelow) = True Then GoTo TopEdge
    If IsEmpty(cellBelow) = False Then GoTo CheckLetter

ElseIf IsEmpty(cellAbove) = True Then Exit Sub
End If

CheckLetter:

    strlengthA = InStr(1, cellAbove, ")")
    strlengthB = InStr(1, cellBelow, ")")

        'set variables for letters in cells above and below the active cell
    CharAbove = Left(cellAbove, 1)
    CharBelow = Left(cellBelow, 1)
    Char = Left(cell, 1)

    If strcell = 2 Then GoTo OriginalFormat 'the only time ) at character 2 happens is a standalone exercise
    If strcell = 3 Then
        If strlengthA = strcell Then            'check if letter in cell above matches current cell letter for superset
            If CharAbove = Char Then            'if cell letters match, then check letter below. If all 3 match, format side edge superset
                If CharBelow = Char Or IsEmpty(cellBelow) = True Then GoTo SideEdge
                Else: GoTo BottomEdge
            End If
                                                'if cell letters don't match, format top edge
            If CharAbove <> Char Then GoTo TopEdge
         End If
    End If

    If strlengthA <> strcell And strlengthA = 2 Then GoTo TopEdge
    If strlengthA <> strcell And strlengthA = 0 And strlengthB = 0 Then GoTo TopEdge

        'see if letter in cell below matches for superset. If it does, format superset, if not diff. format

        If strlengthB = 0 Or strlengthB = 1 Or strlengthB > 3 Then Exit Sub
        If strlengthB = 2 Then GoTo BottomEdge
        If strlengthB = strcell Then
            If CharBelow = Char Then GoTo TopEdge
            If CharBelow <> Char Then GoTo BottomEdge
        End If
'...formatting labels below...
```

Worksheet change event below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call superset_exercise(Target)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am creating lists of exercises for athletes - each list has a specific format (see picture) [Exercise Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ns2x.png). The table may be any number of rows in length. They should be able to be created anywhere within a spreadsheet - different sports have different sheet design needs.

Cell contents will be used for formulas in other dependent ranges of the sheet, formatted identically. These show different calculated properties for each item in the parent list. In this case, weight lifting exercises and their volume, tonnage, and intensity. Calculated tables are usually either horizontal or vertical relative to the parent table and grouped to be able to hide them from view.

My code obviously does not format the dependent ranges either, just the area I am typing. But just this is giving me headaches.

The big end goal is for me to be able to type a table up and have it auto format the other tables as well - it would save me tons of time with many athletes. For now I'd take just being able to format 1 table at a time.

Comment: You shouldn't need all this code to accomplish what you want.  Have a look at https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1950-excel-add-border-automatically.html

Comment: I appreciate the comment, although not sure what you are referring to. I am very much a beginner at vba so I have absolutely no doubt my code is all over the place!  But, I didn't see a way to accomplish this at extendoffice before I started--I don't want borders between every line, only lines with different letters. I had previously tried conditional formatting, and it didn't work as I wished. Apologies if I misundstand what you were telling me.

Comment: Please note: Change this variable name `Dim Char` because `Char` is a type and therefore a reserved keyword in VBA that should never be used as variable name! • Also if you declare `Dim MyChar, CharAbove, CharBelow As String` only the last variable is declared as `String` all the others are of type `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim MyChar As String, CharAbove As String, CharBelow As String`. Check the same for your other `Dim` statements.

Comment: PEH - Thanks a ton for the heads-up on Char and declarations!  I'll change those. Told ya I'm a newbie lol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirly understand your goal but I can give you a few advice how to go on:

1. Try to structure your code to avoid `GoTo`. Repeated/reusable codes should be put in a sub.
2. `IsEmpty()` returns bool. `If IsEmpty(cellAbove) = True Then` is equivalent with `If IsEmpty(cellAbove) Then`.
3. `Worksheet_SelectionChange` fires on every single cursor move. I would check if the active cell is in the range to be processed, like this:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 
        Dim WorkRange as Range
        Set WorkRange = Range("B4:E9")
        If Application.Intersect(Target, WorkRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  ' out of range
        ....
   ```

+1. Do not give up. 3 full days are nothing to prepare the first workable macro :)

Comment: AcsErno - Thanks a ton for the pointers!  I will explain what I am trying  to get done in the next comment...please bear with me as I am typing on my phone. Computer is currently in Windows Update hell and unusable until that's finished...

Comment: Goal: As a strength and conditioning coach, I spend a lot of time writing programs for athletes in excel. I will write 1-10 programs every day, so this is something that will save significant time. I face 2 issues--1) each athlete requires a slightly different exercise selection and 2) each sport requires it's own Excel sheet layout, so always putting a table in 1 column/row position is not feasible and there will be data below and above the table of exercises.


Exercises are grouped in different ways, single, circuit, superset etc. Each exercise is in a separate row (cont...)

Comment: Each exercise in separate row, columns like so:

Col 1) exercise letter/number combo. Designates order of exercise. Letter gives the group, number gives the order.

EXAMPLE: A) bench press B) pull up C) push-up means do each exercise separately, then move on. A1). A2). A3). Means do all 3 in a circuit, before going on.
I want Excel to look for context clues in the 1st column and format my range with specific cell border combinations as I type depending on the letter/number combo present.
 Col 2) exercise name

Col 3-6) rep progressions

Comment: Lastly, Want to clarify - "1st column" doesn't mean Column A, it means whatever column I start typing in...so pretty much any range in the sheet. I want Excel to look for specific alphanumeric combos as the cue to format, and do it automatically while I type